# Как мне с помощью одного скрипта управлять сразу двумя объектами в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-android

Скрипт повешен *сразу на двух* объектах. При нажатии на кнопку управления на экране слева, 2 куба должны двигаться по заданной оси. С помощью `event trigger` настроил управление, но только для одного куба. Как настроить, чтобы двигались одновременно 2 объекта?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем 1 куб является наследником другого. Можно вынуть дочерний куб из наследника. + желательно прикрепить код.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Т.к. один куб является чайлдом второго куба - достаточно двигать только куб-парент и тогда будут двигаться оба одновременно и на одинаковое расстояние.

Comment: Двигается только один

Comment: Значит двигаешь ЧАЙЛД, а не ПАРЕНТ. Сам скрипт повесь на парент. И двигай именно парент.

Comment: Скрипт и так на паренте, парент двигается, чайлд нет.

Comment: Чайлды ВСЕГДА двигаются с парентами. Потому что в этом суть чайлдов - они в относительной системе координат, а не в абсолютной. Или ты чего-то недоговариваешь или говоришь неправду.